# JSON variable is not passed to ajax function

Tags: json, ajax

Here is the Ajax Code. I am using this ajax code to pass the details to the php page and the php file is supposed to return an array value as true or false depending on the condition. I have used json_encode but it doesn't seem to work

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "join_form.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        contact: contact,
        role: role,
        dialcode: dialcode,
        countrycode: countrycode
      },
      cache: false,
      // var data = JSON.parse(data);
      success: function(data) {
      data = $.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(data);
      if(data.status == 'false')
      {
        alert("Something went wrong");
      }
      else
      {
        alert("Message submitted successfully");
        $("#joinForm").trigger("reset");
      }
            // alert(dialcode+countrycode);


        }

        });
    $("#joinForm").trigger("reset");

  });
```

Here is the Php file (join_form.php). 
This php file checks for validity of fields and stores a false value
 in the 
array on which I use json_encode function so that it can
 be returned to ajax. But on returning nothing happens.
 It shows blank function.
 if else functions are not executed. Please help

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "kites";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    alert("Connection failed");
}
else
{
$response = array();
// Check for empty fields
if(
      empty($_POST['name'])     || 
      empty($_POST['email'])    ||
      empty($_POST['contact'])  ||
      empty($_POST['role']) ||
      empty($_POST['dialcode']) ||
      empty($_POST['countrycode'])  
   )

{
  echo "No arguments Provided!";
  $response['status']='false';
}

else{
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $contact = $_POST['contact'];
   $role = $_POST['role'];
   $dialcode = $_POST['dialcode'];
   $countrycode = $_POST['countrycode'];

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from join_form WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            // $stmt->close();
            $response['status'] = 'false';
        } else {
            // user not existed
            // $stmt->close();
            $response['status'] = 'true';
        }
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
echo json_encode($response);



$sql = "INSERT INTO join_form (name,email,contact,role,dialcode,countrycode)
VALUES ('$name','$email','$contact','$role','$dialcode','$countrycode')";




 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
       $response['status'] = 'true';
} 
else {    
    echo "Please do it again";
    $response['status'] = 'false';
    // echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
  echo json_encode($response);

}
}     
?>
```

Comment: `$this->conn` ? You might want to test the PHP outside of the AJAX call first to work out the bugs, or at least be checking the actual response in the console.

Comment: The console is blank... If I remove the data thing in success function and execute the code, the php comnection works and data gets stored... The Ajax and success functions are working but the JSON is not getting passed from php to ajax function...

Comment: I meant check the network tab in the console to view the response from the PHP script. If you have public access to this page and want me to take a look, let me know.

Comment: Okk will check that and let you know

Comment: You were right. The error is in $this. Found in console. There is no response from the php page. It shows the following error

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\wamp\www\kites\join_form.php on line 47

Comment: After removing $this, it stores the data in the database but does not return any alert message whether successfull or failed. What could be the reason behind it??

Comment: Is the JS console still blank? You have a `console.log(data)` in your `success` callback, is that not running? If not, try using `complete` instead of `success`, because `success` only runs if there are no issues: http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: How to use the complete function?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Got the solution by explicitly declaring associative array inside json_encode and removing unnecessary echo statements in php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove all the un-needed echos from your php, and keep only the last one 'echo json_encode($response);'.

Than you don't need to parse the returned response in your ajax call. So you will get your status and you can do something with it.

Alternatively if you wnat also to return the messages you are echoing than you can do the following:

```
$response['status'] = 'false';
$response['message'] = 'No arguments Provided!';

echo json_encode(response).
```

And than in your ajax call response:

```
if(data.status == 'false')
  {
    alert(data.message);
  }
}
```

NOTE: remove the 'HEADER's from your php, you also don't need this. In the ajax call you have set 'data-type = json' and this is enough. The data will be sent back with the appropriate headers automatically!

You are passing the variable to your your data:

```
data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        contact: contact,
        role: role,
        dialcode: dialcode,
        countrycode: countrycode
      },
```

from where do you get those values?
If they are coming from a form you will need to refer to them:

```
var name = $('#name').val()
... and so on.
```

Maybe you already did that but You are not posting your complete code n order to give me the possibility to spot your problem. And by the way, down voting the answer before you will post the complete code in here don't really help.

If you don't post also your HTML I can not see that.

NOTE: You answer with a 'Nothing worked' doesn't really help, and you don't mention the errors you are eventually receiving, so I still have to guess.

Comment: Okk Franco. Will do that and let you know whether it works or not

Comment: You are passing the variable to your your data:

Comment: Hey got the solution.

Comment: I removed all unnecessary echo and included only one echo statement and used associative array by declaring it inside the json parse function... Don't know how but somehow it worked. Thank you for your help

Comment: I am glad I could help you. You have first down voted my answer, I will appreciate if you will correct this and up-vote it

Comment: I am really sorry  for that. I put a tick against it as it worked. I also tried to up-vote it but i am not bale to. I says i will be able to do it only after i get 15 reputation. I will surely vote it up as soon as I will be allowed to do it